# Little/Big Endian conversion

Tags: java, array, integer, serialization

I wanted to make sure that my code is properly converting between the two endians.

Here is the code where I read in an integer:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the integer:");
                    int  number = input.nextInt();

                    System.out.println("At what word address would you like to store the data (must be multiple of 4)?");
                    wordAddress = input.nextInt();

                    if(wordAddress != 0 || wordAddress != 4) {
                        wordAddress = wordAddress / 4;
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j<2; j++){
                        memoryBlock[wordAddress][3] = (byte) (number & 0xFF);   
                        memoryBlock[wordAddress][2] = (byte) ((number >> 8) & 0xFF);   
                        memoryBlock[wordAddress][1] = (byte) ((number >> 16) & 0xFF);   
                        memoryBlock[wordAddress][0] = (byte) ((number >> 24) & 0xFF);
                    }
```

Here is the code where I read in a string:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the string:");
                    String s = input.next();
                    char[] firstArray = s.toCharArray();
                    char[] sArray = { 0, 0, 0, 0};


                    for(int i = 0; i<firstArray.length; i++){
                        sArray[i] = firstArray[i];
                    }


                    System.out.println("At what word address would you like to store the data (must be multiple of 4)?");
                    wordAddress = input.nextInt();

                    if(wordAddress != 0 || wordAddress != 4) { 
                        wordAddress = wordAddress / 4;
                    }
                    int j = 0;
                    for (int i = sArray.length-1; i>=0; i--){

                        memoryBlock[wordAddress][j] = (byte) sArray[i];
                    j++;

                    }
```

Conversion logic:

```
public static void converToLittleEndian(){

        byte [][] conversionBlock = new byte[20][4];


        int k = 3;
        for(int i = 0; i < memoryBlock.length-4; i++){

                conversionBlock[i][0] = memoryBlock[i][3];
                conversionBlock[i][1] = memoryBlock[i][2];
                conversionBlock[i][2] = memoryBlock[i][1];
                conversionBlock[i][3] = memoryBlock[i][0];  
        }

        for(int i = 16; i<20; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<memoryBlock[j].length; j++){
                conversionBlock[i][j] = memoryBlock[i][j];
            }
        }
```

Here is a sample input/output:

> ```
> Would you like to start with a big endian (B) or little endian (L) memory system?
> l
> Would you like to enter a string (S), integer (I) or convert (C) to big endian?
> s
> Please enter the string:
> word
> At what word address would you like to store the data (must be multiple of 4)?
> 0
> Would you like to enter a string (S), integer (I) or convert (C) to big endian?
> s
> Please enter the string:
> a
> At what word address would you like to store the data (must be multiple of 4)?
> 4
> Would you like to enter a string (S), integer (I) or convert (C) to big endian?
> i
> Please enter the integer:
> 1234
> At what word address would you like to store the data (must be multiple of 4)?
> 8
> Would you like to enter a string (S), integer (I) or convert (C) to big endian?
> i
> Please enter the integer:
> 12
> At what word address would you like to store the data (must be multiple of 4)?
> 12
> Would you like to enter a string (S), integer (I) or convert (C) to big endian?
> c
> Outputting little endian memory system contents: 
> A0:     'd' 'r' 'o' 'w' 
> A4:      00  00  00 'a' 
> A8:      00  00  4  -46 
> A12:     00  00  00  12 
> A16:     00  00  00  00 
> A20:     00  00  00  00 
> A24:     00  00  00  00 
> A28:     00  00  00  00 
> A32:     00  00  00  00 
> A36:     00  00  00  00 
> A40:     00  00  00  00 
> A44:     00  00  00  00 
> A48:     00  00  00  00 
> A52:     00  00  00  00 
> A56:     00  00  00  00 
> A60:     00  00  00  00 
> Outputting big endian memory system contents: 
> A0:     'w' 'o' 'r' 'd' 
> A4:     'a'  00  00  00 
> A8:      -46  4  00  00 
> A12:     12  00  00  00 
> A16:     00  00  00  00 
> A20:     00  00  00  00 
> A24:     00  00  00  00 
> A28:     00  00  00  00 
> A32:     00  00  00  00 
> A36:     00  00  00  00 
> A40:     00  00  00  00 
> A44:     00  00  00  00 
> A48:     00  00  00  00 
> A52:     00  00  00  00 
> A56:     00  00  00  00 
> A60:     00  00  00  00
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Unnecessary loop

In this code, you loop 2 times:

> ```
>                 for (int j = 0; j<2; j++){
>                     memoryBlock[wordAddress][3] = (byte) (number & 0xFF);   
>                     memoryBlock[wordAddress][2] = (byte) ((number >> 8) & 0xFF);   
>                     memoryBlock[wordAddress][1] = (byte) ((number >> 16) & 0xFF);   
>                     memoryBlock[wordAddress][0] = (byte) ((number >> 24) & 0xFF);
>                 }
> ```

I'm not sure why you do this twice because nothing is different between the first loop and the second loop.

## Unnecessary if

In this if statement, the condition is always true:

> ```
>                if(wordAddress != 0 || wordAddress != 4) {
> ```

## Buffer overflow

Here, you overflow your buffer, `sArray`, if you input a string longer than 4 characters:

> ```
>                 char[] firstArray = s.toCharArray();
>                 char[] sArray = { 0, 0, 0, 0};
>
>                 for(int i = 0; i<firstArray.length; i++){
>                     sArray[i] = firstArray[i];
>                 }
> ```

Your function `converToLittleEndian()` also has potential buffer overflows, and it's unclear what is happening to rows 16..19.

Comment: Thanks! Fortunately the buffer overflow will not happen because I have checks for that in other parts of the program. Good catch on all 3 parts.